# STM32 reading digital microphone noise

Tags: stm32, adc, noise, microphone, xmega

I have a admp401 digital microphone when I play 8khz tone I get this:
[image]

and when I connect the ADC directly to a signal generator, I get this:
[image]

ADC sampling cycles is set to 55.5 cycles with 12MHZ clock speed.
timer triggers ADC and then the result is sent to DMA. I receive 2000 sample and when it is done, I send all 2000 data to the computer.
This is the output of ADMP401 when the room is quiet.

I use USB power and give it to 5v lm2576 and then, there is a lm1117 for 3.3v . I have enough 100nf and 1uf and 10uf capacitor on my power line. I also got the same result with xmega24a4u on some kind of same PCB with same power supply.
[image]

I disconnected the stm32f103c8t6 blue pill from my board and connected it directly to computer with programmer 3.3v and the I still have the same noise.

My problem is that the microphone output is not symmetric and the bottom of the signal is distorted and the signal looks to noisy.

this is the link of my module  [link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Hot-selling-ADMP401-ADMP404-MEMS-Microphone_62125732904.html)

and here is the schematic (I did reverse engineering and I drew it myself. There might be some errors I do not take any responsibility about it.)
I do not know the values of capacitors.
[image]

Comment: How is the microphone connected to STM32? And that's not a digital microphone, it has analog output.

Comment: I use a Chinese module that microphone is mounted on it. I directly connect the output of module to ADC.

Comment: so, what is your question? ... you described the problem, but you did not say what you want to know

Comment: @jsotola My problem is that the microphone output is not symmetric and the bottom of the signal is distorted signal looks too nosiy.

Comment: you already said that ... what do you want to ask about the problem? ... this site is not a discussion forum ... it is a Q&A site

Comment: I want to know why my signal is so noisy and the the bottom of signal is distorted. That is my question.

Comment: @SeAlGhz But we can't answer your question, because we have no idea which Chinese microphone module you are using, how it works, how you have connected it to STM32.  Maybe the problem is that you have just connected them together without figuring out how they should be connected?

Comment: I am sorry. this is the link of my module  [link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Hot-selling-ADMP401-ADMP404-MEMS-Microphone_62125732904.html)   I could not find more information about the schematic of my module.

Comment: @SeAlGhz Please note that this is not a support forum for random Alibaba items. If the item has no documentation how to use or connect it, why did you buy it in the first place? How are we supposed to know any better how it should be connected? Try asking the seller for manual, datasheet, schematics or other instructions.

Comment: I was spending last hour reverse engineering the schematic. I will edit my question right now.